# Render image on webpage from pixel array

Tags: javascript, python, web

I have a python array with shape 64x64x3. Thus 64 width, 64 height and 3 RGB pixel values.
How do I render this pixel array on my website?
Is there for example a way to let the `<img>` tag read in a pixel array instead of a filename?

Solutions with JavaScript arrays are good as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `<canvas>` element and render the pixels programmatically.

[The MDN has a great article on canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas#Grayscaling_and_inverting_colors) where they give an example of reading and writing pixels programatically.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('rasterCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// get current raster data
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var data = imageData.data;

// prepare data
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i] = Math.random() * 255; 
}

// draw newly modified pixels back onto the canvas
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="rasterCanvas" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red"></canvas>
```

Comment: Please note that my (and all other clientside methods) will suffer from lack of compression while you transfer the RGB array values, unless you compress the sent data yourself. Rendering it server-side to a compressible format may save bandwidth, especially on large graphics. (See Bart's answer for example)

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the array to an image file first, and then link it using the `<img>` tag.

Here's an example using the `PIL` library:

```
from PIL import Image

imageFile = Image.new('RGB', (len(myArray[0]), len(myArray)))
imageFile.putdata([tuple(p) for row in myArray for p in row])
imageFile.save("example.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

For a full Javascript based answer see below. I went with [HTML5 Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/kab/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) as it's easy to use and you can just set individual pixels on your canvas.

**Note:** The array is only 5x5x3 because I did it by hand, but the concept should be fairly obvious.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('imageCanvas').getContext('2d');
var imageData = [
 [[255,0,0], [255,0,0], [255,0,0], [255,0,0], [255,0,0]],
  [[0,255,0], [0,255,0], [0,255,0], [0,255,0], [0,255,0]],
  [[255,0,0], [255,0,0], [255,0,0], [255,0,0], [255,0,0]],
  [[0,255,0], [0,255,0], [0,255,0], [0,255,0], [0,255,0]],
  [[255,0,0], [255,0,0], [255,0,0], [255,0,0], [255,0,0]],
];

for(var y = 0; y < imageData.length; y++){
 for(var x = 0; x < imageData[y].length; x++){
   ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${imageData[y][x][0]}, ${imageData[y][x][1]}, ${imageData[y][x][2]})`;
  ctx.fillRect( x, y, 1, 1 );
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="imageCanvas" width="64" height="64" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```

Comment: I see others are using putImageData which is also a great option. However, you would still have to get your Python array into Javascript so it's up to you how you store the pixel array.

Comment: I just tried it in a fiddle, for 1920x1080 image, and it freezes my browser for over 5 seconds. https://jsfiddle.net/sebi_/y1kbr80z/24/ See console for timings, most of the time is spent evaluating the script and inside fillRect.

Comment: @Sebi Perhaps it's not the most efficient for 1920x1080 images. However, you specified in your question that you are dealing with 64x64 images.